# plugin to make specific post appear

Tags: plugins

i'm not new to wp but new to wpdev, so here is my current challenge:

I need to realise this:

1. random visitor comes onto my webpage
2. the page loads with h1, h2, some text, and a box which asks the person to input their date of birth into the box
3. the person types their date of birth, click's the 'submit' button
4. wp gives out content below the box, based on some calculations to do with their date of birth. The content will be text with some images(its basically their horoscope).

My question to the wise ones here is:

1) Is there a plugin already that I can use to bascially 'map' answers by user to specific post or text? If yes what is the general name for such plugins? (i can't even think of what they are called)

2) If there is no (1), then I dont mind learning how to build one, but I need somewhere to start - which plugin can I take appart to learn how to 'map' visitor responses onto what content then shows up on the page?

3) any other advice?

After this plugin, I will need another similar plugin where a person chooses between A and B answers to several questions, and then I give out text as output (i.e. a personality test type of thing).

Comment: Hi, Welcome to WPSE. Unfortunately i don't know about any plugin that does that (others may still know) but if you want to do it yourself, you need to add more details, such as how the posts will be filtered by a birth date? This will require an AJAX request + a function to send the data back.